# Gatling validate scenarii

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

Before sending my scenarii to our Jenkins/Gatling instance I would like to validate them on my laptop where I write them. Actually I run gatling locally and stop it as soon as it starts, but this is not optimal and I look for a solution to check them with **scalac** as Gatling does not have a check option. 
But when running scalac on scenario I always have

> Homepage.scala:1: error: object duration is not a member of package
>   concurrent import scala.concurrent.duration._

How do you validate your scenario, can someone helps me using scalac ?

Thanks !

Comment: That's weird. Are you using an old version of scala? I'm pretty sure scala.concurrent.duration is in the standard library. Maybe you have another package called scala? In that case you can use an absolute import, `_root_.scala.concurrent.duration._`.

Comment: Post your code. Otherwise, we're just guessing

Comment: At this point, the only sane explanation is that you're running Scala 2.9 or older.

Comment: scala version 2.9.2 under debian wheezy

Comment: Posting complete answer below, then.

Comment: Might be worth looking into https://github.com/lkishalmi/gradle-gatling-plugin for dependency management across environments

Answer (score 1):

Scala version numbering uses the following rule: "Epoch"."Major"."Minor"."Fix".

Major versions, that happen every 2 year or so, are not binary compatible, meaning that you can't run a code compiled with a 2.11 compiler with a 2.10 runtime and vice-versa.

Here, you're trying to use the `scala.concurrent.duration` package that was introduced in Scala 2.10, but you're running with 2.9. Obviously, this package doesn't exist in this version, and that's exactly what the compiler tells you.

- If you're running Gatling 1.X (EOL'ed), you have to use Scala 2.9.
- If you're running Gatling 2.0.X, you have to use Scala 2.10.
- If you're running Gatling 2.1.X, you have to use Scala 2.11.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I use Gatling 2.0.1 and it works well with scala 2.9 even if I can't compile my scenarii with scalac

Comment: The Gatling bundle ships a proper scala-compiler and doesn't use the one in your path.